# How come photons have no mass if they have energy and $E=mc^2$?

Tags: special-relativity, photons, mass, mass-energy

If photons have no mass, and yet have energy, how is that compatible with $E=mc^2$? Anything having mass should have energy (and the opposite should be true as well no)?

Comment: Related, possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2229/123208 & https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/62744/123208

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E=mc^2$ is a statement about energy in the rest frame. The photon rest frame does not exist but one can approach it in principle  by moving along with a photon at near light speed. The photon will be red shifted and its energy will approach zero. In this limit $E=mc^2=0$.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks a lot!